# How to install jsconcpp in ubuntu 14.04 for C++ development?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, compiling, c++, code-blocks

As the question tells how should I install [jsonccpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) in ubuntu 14.04. I have downloaded the jsoncpp-src-0.5.0.tar.gz form [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsoncpp/). Then I opened nautilus using sudo and copied,pasted and extracted the tar.gz file in `/opt`. I have installed the cmake and used this code to install as suggested in the jsoncpp github

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debug -DBUILD_STATIC_LIBS=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF \
      -DARCHIVE_INSTALL_DIR=. -G "Unix Makefiles"
```

But its giving this error

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/opt/jsoncpp-src-0.5.0" does not
appear to contain CMakeLists.txt. Specify --help for usage, or press
the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

- Codeblocks is used as C++ development IDE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your installation with `cmake` fails because you are downloading a very *old* version of `jsoncpp` from SourceForge , a version that actually does *not* use cmake. The file README.txt with the 0.5.0 tarball has the details:

```
* Building/Testing:
 =================

JsonCpp uses Scons (http://www.scons.org) as a build system. Scons
requires python to be installed (http://www.python.org).
```

Newer versions of `jsoncpp` are seen on GitHub (latest stable version is 1.7.3) and these actually *do* use `cmake` to build.

However a reasonable version exists in the Trusty Repositories and the following command will get you `jsoncpp 0.6.0`:

```
sudo apt-get install libjsoncpp-dev libjsoncpp0
```

Here are the details of the package on my system:

```
andrew@corinth:~$ apt-cache policy libjsoncpp-dev
libjsoncpp-dev:
  Installed: 0.6.0~rc2-3ubuntu1
  Candidate: 0.6.0~rc2-3ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 0.6.0~rc2-3ubuntu1 0
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
andrew@corinth:~$
```

If you need a newer version this can be built from source but perhaps this version is enough for your purposes...

Comment: I have installed using sudo and I am using codeblocks as the IDE but its not recognizing the header `#include <json/json.h>` json/json.h: No such file or directory

Comment: @Eka Try the command `sudo find /usr -name json.h` Running this on my Trusty system shows `/usr/include/jsoncpp/json/json.h`

Comment: Hey thanks  for the info . It was in the same location but error was in the naming header. I used `#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>` and now its working

Comment: @Eka Great news! And you have a good day as well :)